# Replaced toilet gasket and now it runs

Tags: toilet

I replaced the gasket on the bottom of my toilet and now a little water (not much) is leaking past the gasket into the bowl. There was no leaking before. I tried pushing the gasket all the way down but it still leaked. Then I added a 2nd gasket and that didn’t do the trick either. It this just common after replacing a new gasket or is there something else I haven’t tried?

Comment: If leaking was common after replacing a new gasket nobody would ever do it.

Comment: You need to do it over, right. That's not "adding another gasket." With a time machine it might be "not fixing something that wasn't broken" but too late for that now. [Edit] to include pictures and someone might be able to offer more detail, but for now, that's what I can offer, other than "call a plumber to fix what you broke" which is your last resort, generally.

Comment: You "replaced the gasket on the bottom of my toilet"... which gasket are you speaking of? The flush valve gasket (aka flapper/ball); the tank-to-bowl gasket; the wax ring? We need to know more to be able to help you...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Neither of the possible 'gaskets' on your toilet (between floor & toilet or between bowl & tank) have any effect on whether or not water runs from the tank into the bowl. John almost certainly has the correct answer below - it's the flapper valve's job to stop water from flowing when the toilet is not actively flushing.

Comment: FYI, adding a second gasket is almost never the answer to any problem requiring gaskets! Examples: double wax rings at the bottom of your toilet - more likely to leak or blow out during aggressive/improper plunging. Double gaskets on your car's oil filter (happens when old gasket sticks to engine during filter removal) - will blow out when engine comes up to pressure.

Answer (score 2):

The flapper valve got bumped or misaligned. For a quick test, use a ruler or a stick to reach down through the water in the tank and push down lightly on the flapper valve. See if that stops the running.